# non ascii csv delimiters ignored in unix

Tags: java, unix, csv, utf-8

I am trying to create a csv file from data retrieved from a database.  The data itself contains commas, pipes and any number of delimiters.  We have chosen to use the non ascii broken pipe symbol ¦ as the delimiter and this also has to be present in xml config files and java test files.

When our java files are deployed to unix, it complains that an invalid character is found, I guess because it's finding a non ascii character in ascii files.

So we converted the files to UTF-8, in windows this shows the ¦ character as a � character.  So we copied the broken pipe symbol from a UTF-8 website.   This now compiles in windows and unix fine.  However, in windows the tests run fine but not in unix, as it's interpreting the ¦ as Â¦

Can anyone advise how I should handle these files and what format they should be in?

The only other solution I can think of right now is using a combination of ascii characters as delimiters, which I don't really want to do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [general approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Toward_standardization) is to quote fields that may contain delimiters.  Embedded quotes are then handled by using two quotes to represent them.  This probably requires more pre/post processing than you are currently doing but will make your code more robust (what happens if the database field starts using the embedded pipe character?).

The [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) project can handle this use case.

Comment: I've split this into 2 comments. Thanks for the response.  The trouble we have is that we are stuck with using an internal csv parser so can't use opencsv at present, so we can't extend it to deal with quoted fields.  I note your point regarding the use of our delimiter in the actual data in the future and this this is a risk.  However, for the present I just need so some help in using the broken pipe character as a delimiter that works in both windows and unix.

Comment: One thought is that the default encoding used on the unix machine is ascii so if we use files that are saved as cp1252 then the character is not interpreted.  However, when we save them as utf-8 they are also not being interpreted correctly.  What I need help with is overccoming this initial issue, then the larger design issue can be tackled later (famous last words :).